# Calling -createDirectoryAtURL: causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsfilemanager

I'm really confused right now. This is my piece of code:

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *backup = [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];
backup = [backup URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Old_Data_File"];

[manager createDirectoryAtURL:backup withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

When this code is executed, it crashes at the last line with the message

> -[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5e59220

How could this be an unrecognized selector?

**EDIT:**

`manager` is not `nil` and printing `backup` to the console results in

> {type = 15, string = file://localhost/Users/fabian/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/D37C5B93-A778-4555-8953-814F823B1116/Documents/Old_Data_File, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}

Until the `Old_Data_File` the path exists, the last component should be created by the file manager...

Comment: make sure `manager` is not null.  Also, is `backup` a valid file URL?

Comment: What version of iOS are you testing on? (This method is iOS 5+/OS X 10.7+.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh... are you targeting iOS 5.0 and newer?  this API does not exist on iOS 4.3.

Comment: Oh! I only now saw the `NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 5_0)`. So I should use the method that takes a `NSString`?

Comment: If you want to support iOS 4.3, 3.X and even 2.0... yep.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this?

```
 (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

AtPath instead of AtURL?